# Why is $M_2 (F)$ a direct sum of two minimal left ideals?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $F$ be a field and $M_2 (F)$ denotes the ring of all $2\times 2$ matrices with entries in $F$.

I was wondering if someone could help me about this claim: Why is $M_2 (F)$  a direct sum of two minimal left ideals?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the fact that $F^2$ is an irreducible left module over $M_2(F)$. Can you think of left ideals that are very naturally isomorphic to this module?

Comment: @Mark What do you mean by irreducible module? You mean simple modules?

Comment: Yes, simple and irreducible are the same thing.

Comment: How can I prove that $F^2$ is a simple $M_2 (F)$-module? This is a theorem?

Comment: Yes, it's a classical result that if $D$ is a division ring then $D^n$ is a simple module over $M_n(D)$.

Comment: For example, you may look up Lam's *A First Course in Non-commutative Rings*.

Comment: @Mark soryy, Could you please tell me how can I  use this fact to solve my question?

Comment: Yes, I have this book.

Comment: I already gave a hint, think of $2$ left ideals which are very naturally isomorphic to this module. Left ideals which are simple modules are minimal left ideals.

Comment: @Mark Tnank you very much for your help.

Comment: The fact $F^n$ is a simple $M_n(F)$ module is really just a theorem from regular linear algebra. For every nonzero vectors $v$ and $w$, you can find a linear transformation mapping $v\mapsto w$.   That mean any nonzero submodule of $F^n$ has to contain all the other elements of $F^n$.